# Ссылка на динамический массив в виде аргумента функции

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

У меня есть динамический массив, пишу функцию для "печати" значений.
Создаю указатель на массив uint8_t в кол-ве count и сразу обнуляю значения:

```
uint8_t * arr = new uint8_t[count]();
```

Функция принимает указатель на динамический массив:

```
void f(uint8_t * arr)
```

Тоже самое, но не создаю копию указателя, а использую передаваемый указатель:

```
void f(uint8_t * &arr)
```

Всё ли верно я понимаю и делаю, и как сказать, что значения менять внутри функции я не собираюсь? В каком месте должен быть `const`?
Что значат квадратные скобки в записи `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` и нужны ли они в моей ситуации?

Comment: Значения, на которые указывает указатель? `void f(const uint8_t * arr)`

Comment: `void f(const uint8_t * &arr)` сыпет ошибками `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type «const uint8_t*&»`. Функция рекурсивная, поэтому хочу работать по ссылке всегда, когда это возможно, но ещё и отметить, что исходные значения не будут изменены (кроме одного, ради которого и рекурсия).

Comment: Зачем вы передаете ссылку?

Comment: @VTT чтобы не плодить копии указателя. Хочу передать ссылку на указатель в функцию, при этом указать, что значения по указателю не будут изменены. Да, и просто ради понимания, как это работает.

Comment: Ссылка обычно представляет собой как раз указатель с другой семантикой.

Comment: Зачем вам "не плодить копии указателя"? Обычно ссылку используют, когда хотят менять именно сам указатель в функции так, чтобы изменения после этого были видны снаружи функции.

Comment: При передаче в функцию указателя по значению вы как поступаете куда эффективнее, так как передавая его по ссылке - вы все равно передаете указатель, только еще и постоянно должны его разыменовывать. Смысл передача по ссылке имеет тогда, когда вы хотите поменять сам указатель "снаружи" - чтобы `arr` стал указывать на что-то другое. Вам это нужно?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//  g++ -c -Wall -Wpedantic transpoint.cpp
# include <cstdint>
# include <cstddef>
void g(uint8_t * x){ }

void h(uint8_t * & x){ }

void i(uint8_t * * x){ }

void cg(uint8_t const * x){
  // тип аргумента слева от const - защищён от изменения
  // данные в массиве изменять нелья,
  // сам указатель можно 
 }

void ch(uint8_t * const & x){
  // слева от const это указатель
  // x - это ссылка на указатель, который менять нельзя
  // а данные можно
  }

void ci(uint8_t * const * x){
  // то-же самое, что ссылка на указатель, но использовать надо 
  // с добавлением ещё одной звёздочки
  // x - это плавающий указатель на константный указатель.
  // x - менять можно , *x - нет
  // (*x)[i] - можно
  }

void f() {
    size_t count = 10 ;
    uint8_t * arr = new uint8_t[count]();
    g(arr);
    h(arr);
    i(&arr);
    cg(arr);
    ch(arr);
    ci(&arr);
    delete[] arr; }

namespace{
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
  // argv - массив указателей char*
  int main(int argc, char * * argv);
  // то-же самое
}
```